# custom filter inside ngRepeat for filtering divs relative to price property of the model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

Trying to use angular custom filter to filter my products by price using
Checkboxes, but need better implementation of my custom filter function so that all cases work as expected.

HTML html with checkboxes for filtering

```
<input id="cb1" type="checkbox" ng-model="priceVal1">
<label for="cb1"><span></span>Under 200</label>

<input id="cb2" type="checkbox" ng-model="priceVal2">
<label for="cb2"><span></span>200 - 400</label>

<input id="cb3" type="checkbox" ng-model="priceVal3">
<label for="cb3"><span></span>400 - 600</label>

<input id="cb4" type="checkbox" ng-model="priceVal4">
<label for="cb4"><span></span>600 - 800</label>

<input id="cb5" type="checkbox" ng-model="priceVal5">
<label for="cb5"><span></span>800 - 1000</label>

<input id="cb6" type="checkbox" ng-model="priceVal6">
<label for="cb6"><span></span>Above 1000</label>
```

HTML TABLE

```
<div ng-repeat="product in appData.products | filter:priceFilterCustom('price', priceVal1, priceVal2, priceVal3, priceVal4, priceVal5, priceVal6)"></div>
```

In controller custom filter function right now is this:

```
$scope.priceFilterCustom = function (priceField, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6) {
            return function predicateFunc(item) {
                    if(val1 == true){
                        return 0 < item[priceField] && item[priceField] <= 200
                    }
                    if(val2 == true){
                        return 200 <= item[priceField] && item[priceField] <= 400
                    }
                    if(val3 == true){
                        return 400 < item[priceField] && item[priceField] <= 600
                    }
                    if(val4 == true){
                        return 600 < item[priceField] && item[priceField] <= 800
                    }
                    if(val5 == true){
                        return 800 < item[priceField] && item[priceField] <= 1000
                    }
                    if(val6 == true){
                        return item[priceField] >= 1000
                    }
            };
        };
```

So the function takes 7 parameters the first is the property we want to filter in my case it will be always 'price' since I want to use this filter only for price filter so in my html i pass it hardcoded as 'price'
the other parameters are true/false/undefined
This works but If i want to click two checkboxes for example first and second
the function takes

`'price' true true false false false false` as parameters and the custom filter does not continue to the `second if` since the `first if` is true and `returns true`

So I'm thinking of a better way for this solution

Answer (score 0):

just use or

```
var res = false;
if(val1 == true){
    res = res || (0 < item[priceField] && item[priceField] <= 200)
}
if(....
return res;
```